Why is my wireless network interface not being recognized?
My wireless network interface is not recognized by wpa_supplicant, ip link show, ifconfig -a, and more. This issue persists on my Gentoo Linux installation and an Arch live environment. The interface seems to be detected as it attempts to load the iwlwifi kernel module, unsuccessfully. dmesg | grep iwlwifi shows probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110.
I've tried options suggested online, such as booting with the kernel parameter iwlwifi.power_save=0, but I'm unsure what else to try. Also worth mentioning my installation remained unbooted since the interface worked, nothing should've been changed within the OS.
Interface information if needed:
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Any help is appreciated.
Wireless connections are automatically established when booting into Windows, so its unlikely a problem with the card itself.

Error -110 is -ETIMEDOUT and the message comes from a generic function that calls a driver's probe function. One possible reason is that the firmware file the driver is feeding the WiFi chip is bad, and the chip fails to start up with that firmware. Look for a message like loaded firmware version <version> <filename> ... and ensure the file named /lib/firmware/<filename> or /usr/lib/firmware/<filename> exists and is not damaged. Compare to linux-firmware git repo, use the plain link to download.

Please edit your question to add the output of lspci -knn -d ::0280 for the purpose of identifying the exact model of the wireless interface chip.

@telcoM, on boot today, everything seems to work without any changes on my end. I am not sure what was going on yesterday, but I will let you know if any other problems arise. Thank you!

@telcoM, randomly stopped working again. Looking at kernel logs I see multiple firmware files being loaded. Not sure which ones are relevant. Updating the post to include the output of lspci.

After researching further on Reddit, I found that Windows was hogging the network card while booted into any other environment.
This can be easily fixed by disabling Fast Startup within the power settings menu.

Exactly.  That why we always say that disabling it is a must when dual-booting. Keep that in mind for the future.
